# Migrate from SQL Server to Cassandra

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration, cassandra

I wish to start very quickly with my new project. I have experience in SQL Server, but no experience with Cassandra, so SQL Server would definitely be the fastest. But IF my project would become successful I would like to migrate to Cassandra. Is that even possible and if so a painstaking job or pretty straightforward?

Comment: The degree of difficulty depends entirely on your data structures and access/query patterns - you'd need to give more details.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

'painstaking' doesn't even begin to describe it... You're talking really really different words.

On the other hand, define 'succesfull'. Is the success of stackoverflow.com itself enough of a measure, with [1 million persons visiting each day](http://www.quantcast.com/p-c1rF4kxgLUzNc)? This very answer you read now is hosted on SQL Server.

Comment: Wow! I didn't know (or expect) that!:) Is there an overview of Stackoverflows technology stack? Is it just MSSQL server for data? Or are other data technologies utilized, such as an earlier comment using sqlpdw or other tools for indexing the data? I can hardly imagine that all questions are retrieved from the DB every single time?

Comment: See [How StackOverflow Scales with SQL Server](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2011/11/how-stackoverflow-scales-sql-server-video/). As for Paralel Data Warehowse (sqlpdw), it is an appliance for data analysis (BI/DW), definitely not something for a web site back end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in java you could try PlayOrm which is very similar to JPA but with noSQL twists of embedding data in your row and such plus it has Scalable SQL so as long as you partition your data correctly, you can still scale and partitions of the table have indices you can query with the SQL....after all, you don't want a trillion node index from a table with 1 trillion rows...instead you can have partitions and query the partitions.